# How to summarize multiple files into one file based on an assigned rule?

Tags: r, csv

I have ~ 100 files in the following format, each file has its own file name, but all these files are save in the same directory, let's said, filecd is follows:

```
   A    B    C    D
ab 0.3  0.0  0.2  0.20
cd 0.7  0.0  0.3  0.77
ef 0.8  0.1  0.5  0.91
gh 0.3  0.5  0.6  0.78
```

fileabb is as follows:

```
   A    B    C    D
ab 0.3  0.9  1.0  0.20
gh 0.3  0.5  0.6  0.9
```

All these files have same number of columns but different number of rows.

For each file I want to summarize them as one row (0 for all cells in the same column are < 0.8; 1 for ANY of the cells in the same column is larger than or equal to 0.8), and the summerized results will be saved in a separate csv file as follows:

```
        A B C D    
filecd  1 0 0 1
fileabb 0 1 1 1
..... till 100
```

Instead of reading files and processing each files separately, could it be done by R efficiently?  Could you give me help on how to do so? Thanks.

For the ease of discussion.  I have add following lines for sample input files:

```
file1 <- data.frame(A=c(0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.3), B=c(0,0,0.1,0.5), C=c(0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6), D=c(0.2,0.77,0.91, 0.78))

file2 <- data.frame(A=c(0.3, 0.3), B=c(0.9,0.5), C=c(1,0.6), D=c(0.2,0.9))
```

Please kindly give me some more advice.  Many thanks.

Comment: What you have tried so far?  Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Your files also do not appear to be csvs. More like fixed width?

Comment: @Andrie I cannot get it work yet.

Comment: @Nick,  No all the files are in csv format.  It is just that I cannot attach the files with this message.  For the ease of discussion, I have edited the question to include sample input files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a vector of all the filenames.

```
filenames <- dir(your_data_dir)  #you may also need the pattern argument
```

Then read the data into a list of data frames.

```
data_list <- lapply(filenames, function(fn) as.matrix(read.delim(fn))) 
#maybe with other arguments passed to read.delim
```

Now calculate the summary.

```
summarised <- lapply(data_list, function(dfr)
{
  apply(x, 2, function(row) any(row >= 0.8))
})
```

Convert this list into a matrix.

```
summary_matrix <- do.call(rbind, summarised)
```

Make the rownames match the file.

```
rownames(summary_matrix) <- filenames
```

Now write out to CSV.

```
write.csv(summary_matrix, "my_summary_matrix.csv")
```

Comment: Sorry I found I cannot get it work yet, could you mind to give me some more guidance?        > filenames <- dir("./")
> data_list <- lapply(filenames, function(fn) as.matrix(read.delim(fn))) 
> 
> summarised <- lapply(data_list, function(dfr)
+ {
+   apply(x, 2, function(row) any(row >= 0.8))
+ })
> 
> do.call(rbind, summarised)
     Name    A    B    C    D
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

Comment: At what point does it fail, and are you certain that all the steps before that result in what you would expect (e.g. have you checked the contents of data_list to indeed be a list of matrices of the right format)?